# Codeception Acceptance Test : How to test inside a PHP function

Tags: php, codeception

Im new working on Codeception environment, i was wondering how to test inside a PHP function i have the following php code :

```
function showLoginForm(){
`echo 'Login';
echo '<form method="POST" action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'">';
echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="Username"><br>';
echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="Password"><br>';
echo '<input type="submit" name="Submit">';
echo '</form>';
}`
```

When I test in Codeception in this way :

```
$I->fillField('Username','jon');
$I->fillField('Password','1234');
```

i got the following error:

Form field by Label or CSS element with 'user' was not found.

I dont have an idea how to do test inside Functions or Conditions like (else, if) in a .php file

Thanks in advance

Comment: Error message does not match your code. Please find a difference.

Comment: Form field by Label or CSS element with 'Username' was not found.

Comment: Acceptance tests do not test functions, they test websites.